# Multiple-line cursor movement in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, osx-mavericks

**(How) can one add a *new*, *custom* keyboard action in *Android Studio*?** Say, can you add a `Move up/down 10 lines` action (and then add a keymap for it)? I've sifted through `Android Studio.app`'s package contents, but couldn't find any relevant .xml or .plist.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something similar to the macro functionality in vim.

This can be done in Android Studio, and then mapped to a key preference as explained in [this blog entry](http://netherlandsdaniel.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-macros-in-android-studio.html) I found by googling "android studio macro".

1. Start recording a a macro in Edit - Macros - Start Macro Recording
2. [PERFORM ANY KEYSTROKES YOU NEED TO INCLUDE IN THE MACRO]
3. Stop the macro recording in Edit - Macros - Stop Macro Recording
4. Give it a cool name

And then you can add a keyboard shortcut for this macro in Keymapping in Preferences.